# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement RecyclerView in one of my custom alert dialogue. Its crashing with error called

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

on this line

```
hsv_font_bartextview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

My function code of custom dialogue is like below

```
private void showGotoPageDialog() {

        final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.font_dialogue);
        mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(SettingsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        hsv_font_bartextview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.hsv_font_bartextview);
        hsv_font_bartextview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        TextAdapterTextview textAdaptertextview = new TextAdapterTextview(SettingsActivity.this, Globle.getFontArray());
        hsv_font_bartextview.setAdapter(textAdaptertextview);
        textAdaptertextview.setOnClickLIstner(new OnTClickLIstner() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, String image, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,image,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        mDialog.show();
        TextView dismiss = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dismiss);
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Let me know if someone can help me for solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: Try `hsv_font_bartextview = (RecyclerView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.hsv_font_bartextview);`, assuming your view is defined within `R.layout.font_dialogue`

Comment: @MichaelDodd You are right...Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hsv_font_bartextview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.hsv_font_bartextview);
```

`findViewById()` returns `null`, because your activity does not have a widget with that ID. Your *dialog* might, but the dialog is not the activity. Call `findViewById()` on the *dialog* if that is where the `hsv_font_bartextview` is.